# Align : 'stretch' not working for Accordion layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

I have included an 'accordion' layout, which is included in 'west' region of a 'border' layout. But the align : 'stretch' property is not working for the accordion layout.

Accordion Layout

```
var user_menu_items = new Ext.Panel({
        layout: 'accordion',
        height: 565,
        align: 'stretch',
        id: 'usermenu',
        items: [{
                layout: 'fit',
                title: 'Configuration',
                id: 'menulist1',
                html: 'Group1 Content',
                collapseFirst: true
            }, {
                title: 'User Action Group2',
                id: 'menulist2',
                html: 'Group2 Content'
            }, {
                title: 'User Action Group3',
                id: 'menulist3',
                html: 'Group3 Content'
            }]
    });
```

Border Layout

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
                layout: 'border',
                defaults: {
                    collapsible: false,
                    split: false,
                    bodyStyle: 'padding:2px'
                },
                items: [{
                        title: 'USER MENU',
                        region: 'west',
                        margins: '5 0 0 0',
                        cmargins: '5 5 0 0',
                        width: 225,
                        minSize: 100,
                        maxSize: 250,
                        collapsible: true,
                        collapsed: false,
                        bodyStyle: 'padding:0px',
                        items: [user_menu_items]
                    }]
              }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

I am using extjs-4.2.2

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting. I tried in my local machine and it seems it is working fine with `width:225` in west side.

Comment: Also you check this fidller link. [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bvu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below:

```
var user_menu_items = new Ext.Panel({
        layout: 'accordion',
        //height: 565,
        //align: 'stretch',
        id: 'usermenu',
        items: [{
                layout: 'fit',
                title: 'Configuration',
                id: 'menulist1',
                html: 'Group1 Content',
                collapseFirst: true
            }, {
                title: 'User Action Group2',
                id: 'menulist2',
                html: 'Group2 Content'
            }, {
                title: 'User Action Group3',
                id: 'menulist3',
                html: 'Group3 Content'
            }]
    });


Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
                layout: 'border',
                defaults: {
                    collapsible: false,
                    split: false,
                    bodyStyle: 'padding:2px'
                },
                items: [{
                        title: 'USER MENU',
                        region: 'west',
                        margins: '5 0 0 0',
                        cmargins: '5 5 0 0',
                        width: 225,
                        minSize: 100,
                        maxSize: 250,
                        collapsible: true,
                        collapsed: false,
                        bodyStyle: 'padding:0px',
                        layout: 'accordion', // <------- ADD THIS LINE TO WEST PANEL.------------------>
                        items: [user_menu_items]
                    }]
              }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Comment: The above code is correctly execute as expected, but an additional tab is now displaying on top of the accordion. (Note: I have made only the changes mentioned in the above code).

Comment: A screenshot of the above mentioned additional tab is attaching

Comment: hi, i've tried it in jsfiddle and haven't seen any problem. https://jsfiddle.net/rkd568tx/

Comment: I have sorted out the issue, actually i was adding one accordion inside another. Issue is fixed now. Thank you Muzzaffer

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, [`Ext.panel.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel) does not have a config option `align`.

What does have a config option [`align`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Accordion-cfg-align) is the [`Ext.layout.container.Accordion`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Accordion).

So the code would be:

```
var user_menu_items = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: {
        type:'accordion',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    height: 565,
    ...
```

Comment: I tried with above code, but it was not giving me proper output.